# Get the Value of a checkBox server Side

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i want to get the value of a checkbox... my Checkbox show the Value of the Database "true" or "false" and the user can change the Value (if he dont like it) 
i get every time the Value false

View:

```
   <%if ((Boolean)ViewData["Statistik3"])
   {%>                            
        <input type="checkbox" name="Statistik3" value="true" checked= "checked"/>
   <%}
    else
   { %>
       <input type="checkbox" name="Statistik3" value="false"/>  <%--</input>--%>
   <%} %>
```

Controller C#

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Formular(string button, string decision1, FormEntries entries )
{
    entries.Statistik3 ? "Yes" : "No"
}
```

Comment: Did you checked whether the ViewData in View have correct value

Comment: yes... i can set the Value like this ViewData["Statistik3"] = db.getStat();   but i cant get theValue if the user set the Box checked....

Comment: is correct the second checkbox with the name: Statistik4?

Comment: No the Checkbox have the same Name

Answer (score 1):

Try rendering the checkbox using a server side Html helper. Don't hardcode input elements as you did in your views because this leads to horrible spaghetti code. So replace the entire code you have shown with a simple call to the `Html.CheckBox` helper which will take care of rendering the proper input element:

```
@Html.CheckBox("Statistik3")
```

and now the controller action you are posting to could take a boolean argument with the same name:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Formular(bool statistik3, string button, string decision1, FormEntries entries)
{
    // you could use the statistik3 boolean argument to determine
    // whether the user checked or not the checkbox
}
```

The next improvement I would do would be to completely get rid of `ViewData` and define a view model that will contain all the information this view requires and then use the strongly typed version of the helper: `Html.CheckBoxFox`.

Comment: i have already testet the Method  @Html.CheckBox("Statistik3) in this case i can get the correct value but i cant Set the Value! its a bug described in the Blog http://weblogs.asp.net/ashicmahtab/archive/2009/03/27/asp-net-mvc-html-dropdownlist-and-selected-value.aspx that is why i was trying to solve the Problem in another way

Comment: I was using this Code in the View <td style="padding:3px"><%= Html.CheckBox("Statistik3", (Boolean)ViewData["Statistik3"], new { @tabindex = "10" })%>     </td>

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes are boolean only types; the value attribute will be ignored and it's only where there is the presence of the absence of the checked attribute. Is you form bound to a data model at all? Try the following:

```
<%if ((Boolean)ViewData["Statistik3"])
{%>                            
    <input type="checkbox" name="Statistik3"  id="Statistik3" checked="checked"/>
<%}
else
{ %>
   <input type="checkbox" name="Statistik3" id="Statistik3"/>  <%--</input>--%>
<%} %>
```

and then test for a boolean value on return.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure the Checkbox is wrapped within a form element. Something like this

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("Formular")){
  <%if ((Boolean)ViewData["Statistik3"])
   {%>                            
        <input type="checkbox" name="Statistik3" value="true" checked= "checked"/>
   <%}
    else
   { %>
       <input type="checkbox" name="Statistik3" value="false"/>  <%--</input>--%>
   <%} %>
<%} %>
```

As suggested above, you should be using @Html.CheckBox("Statistik3")